# Index.html not link to app.component in electron angular

Tags: angular, electron, angular10

I am trying to add electron to the existing angular project.

I am add like new application and I think I configure correctly but when I run my electron app, nothing show at screen.

this is main.js, how I load index.html of electron app.

```
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('./src/index.html')      
  win.setMenu(null);
}
```

index.html=>

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<h1 class="app-root">Welcome to sub-app1!</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this is the app-router.component.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'test',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I add a console to app.component.ts's constructor but nothing print.

When I run this electron sub-application, nothing shows on the screen. Looks like index and app.component.ts, not link.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

follow [this](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) repository. it'll help you to set angular with development env as well as production env.